# Let $X, Y$ be random variables. Then: $1.$ If $X, Y$ are independent and ...

Tags: probability, probability-theory, covariance

Let $X, Y$ be random variables. Then:

$1.$ If $X, Y$ are independent and $Z=X*Y$, then $Cov(X,Z)=EY*VarX$

$2.$ If $X, Y$ are independent and $Z=X*Y$, then $Cov(X,Z)=EY*VarX+VarY$

$3.\ Var(X+Y)=VarX+VarY-2Cov(X,Y) $

$4.$ If $X, Y$ are independent, then $Var(X*Y)=EX^2*VarY+(EY)^2*VarX$

$5.$ If $X, Y$ are independent, then $Var(X+Y)>Var(X-Y)$

My question is: is there any scheme for doing such exercises and do I have to know any specific formulas (except that $VarX=EX^2-(EX)^2$ and $Cov(X,Y)=E(XY)-EXEY$) to make these? 
I will appreciate any effort at helping me with this problem

**edit 2:**

$ad.1.$ $Cov(X,Z)=Cov(X,XY)=E(XXY)-E(X)E(XY)=E(X^2Y)-E(X)E(X)E(Y)=E(X^2)E(Y)-(EX)^2E(Y)=E(Y)[E(X^2)-(EX)^2] =EY*VarX $

$ad.2.$ $Cov(X,Z)=Cov(X,XY)=E(XXY)-E(X)E(XY)=E(X^2Y)-E(X)E(X)E(Y)=E(X^2)E(Y)-(EX)^2E(Y)=E(Y)[E(X^2)-(EX)^2] \neq EY*VarX + VarY$

$ad.3.$ $Var(X+Y)=VarX+VarY+2Cov(X,Y) \neq VarX+VarY-2Cov(X,Y) $

$ad.5.$ $Var(X+Y)=Var(X-Y)$, so there's no inequality

Comment: I mean, technically, you don't even need those two formulas. All you need are definitions of expectation and (co)variance, although other formulas some times make calculations simpler and connections easier to see.

Comment: It's not clear to me what kind of answer you want from us. There is no "scheme" for answering these questions---like Arthur said, you look at what the problem is asking of you, and you look at your definitions, and try to prove each statement...

Comment: I have edited my post. I want from you to check it and write any tips.

Answer (score 2):

These seem like introductory exercices on the basis definitions.
Like you've used, if $X, Y$ are random variables
$$
\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y) = \mathrm{E}(XY) - \mathrm{E}(X)\mathrm{E}(Y),
$$
and $\mathrm{Var}(X) = \mathrm{Cov}(X,X)$.

Your solution to the first is not right though.
$$
 \mathrm{E}(X^2) \not = \mathrm{E}(X)^2
$$

It might help to think about a distribution for this. Let $X\sim N(0,1)$ then $\mathrm{E}(X) = 0$. However $\mathrm{E}(X^2) \not = \mathrm{E}(X)^2 = 0$. This makes sense because $X^2$ has nothing but positive values. Even more, the distribution is $X^2 \sim \chi^2$. So $\mathrm{E}(X^2) = 1$. (Or notice how here $\mathrm{Var}(X) = \mathrm{E}(X^2) - \mathrm{E}(X)^2$ which implies $1 = \mathrm{E}(X^2) - 0$)